# How can we handle special characters in the URL with Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, router

Currently , I have a url like this:

```
http://localhost/foo/barbar(2222)
```

but it doesn't work with Angular when I try to open it in the tab. It shows an error like this:

> Error: Cannot match any routes: '2222'

How can we handle this problem in Angular. To get the result as if we open it with encoded url : http://localhost/foo/barbar%282222%29

Comment: How have you defined your routes?

Comment: already define that. it works fine when I use url without special characters like this 

`http://localhost/foo/barbar2222`

Comment: We'll still need to see your routes definition in order to see what may be going wrong.

Comment: @ranieuwe my route looks like this
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/181f2a1614c43b45e818570771271930

Answer (score 2):

At this momment, it is a bug with Router component. There is a workaround that fixes it. You must extend `encodeUri`.

```
encodeURIComponent(str) {
    return encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/[!'()*]/g, function (c) {
        return '%' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16);
    });
}
```

Check the issue at Angular's GitHub repo.

> https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4895

Comment: in 2022 this bug still isn't solved